# Error using Java generics, ? extends clause

Tags: java, generics

I have got a treeitem object with user object of type `MyNode`:

```
final TreeItem<? extends MyNode> parent = treeItem.getParent();
final ObservableList<TreeItem<? extends MyNode>> children = parent.getChildren();
```

Using the `? extends` in java generics gives me the following error:

```
Found: ObservableList<javafx.scene.control.TreeItem<? extends MyNode>>
Required: ObservableList<javafx.scene.control.TreeItem<capture <? extends MyNode>>>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
final ObservableList<? extends TreeItem<? extends MyNode>> children = parent.getChildren();
```

it should work.